# Как реализовать копирование и перемещение директорий и папок на Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Подскажите какой-нибудь адекватный способ копирования и перемещения директорий и папок на Node.js.

К сожаления, сам ничего найти не смог.
Спасибо

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13786160/copy-folder-recursively-in-node-js

Answer (score 0):

Можете использовать [ncp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ncp)

```
var ncp = require('ncp').ncp;
 
ncp.limit = 16;
 
ncp(source, destination, function (err) {
 if (err) {
   return console.error(err);
 }
 console.log('done!');
});
```

Или же используйте [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { COPYFILE_EXCL } = fs.constants;

// destination.txt will be created or overwritten by default.
fs.copyFileSync('source.txt', 'destination.txt');
console.log('source.txt was copied to destination.txt');

// By using COPYFILE_EXCL, the operation will fail if destination.txt exists.
fs.copyFileSync('source.txt', 'destination.txt', COPYFILE_EXCL);
```

Comment: Это же асинхронный метод, правильно понимаю?

Comment: Да, а в чем проблема?

Comment: Вы просили адекватный способ. Асинхронный он как раз адекватный.

Comment: Обновил добавил пример синхронного